# EncryptCookie and Session in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have problems with working with larvel sessions.

I am trying to get session id using `Session::getId()` in laravel but every time I refresh the page I get a diffrent value. I commented the `EncryptCookies::class` middleware it worked fine.

In `config\session.php`  I change the domain to my site domain `ddev.dev` and the path is set to '\'.

[EDIT]

In SessionHandler::class middleware I echo the session id.
here is my `app\Http\kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Dideo\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Dideo\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Dideo\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfig::class,
    \Dideo\Http\Middleware\SessionHandler::class,
];
```

Comment: are you using the web middleware? apparently in 5.2 you need to be using web middleware for sessions etc otherwise I am assuming it is regenerating a new session..

Comment: what is web middleware?? my SessionHandler::class which I echo the session id is in global middleware